# Which of the following two codes is better in terms of execution efficiency?

Tags: flutter

May I ask which of the following two codes is better in terms of execution efficiency? Which one is recommended?

```dart
 Widget buildItem(){

    final List<Widget> items = [];

    if(this.widget.showItem1){
      items.add(Row(children: <Widget>[
        Container(),
        Container(),
      ]));
    }

    if(this.widget.showItem2){
      items.add(Row(children: <Widget>[
        Container(),
        Container(),
      ]));
    }

    if(this.widget.showItem3){
      items.add(Row(children: <Widget>[
        Container(),
        Container(),
      ]));
    }

    return Column(children: items);
  }
```

```dart
Widget buildItem(){
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      this.widget.showItem1 ?  Row(children: <Widget>[Container(), Container(),]): Container(),
      this.widget.showItem2 ?  Row(children: <Widget>[Container(), Container(),]): Container(),
      this.widget.showItem3 ?  Row(children: <Widget>[Container(), Container(),]): Container(),
    ],);
  }
```

Comment: which one is more recommended?
due to the definition of variables and manipulation of objects, will the first one affect efficiency?@MZ

Comment: They are not equivalent. They are doing two different things so it's hard to compare them... one adds a `Container` when `showItemX` is false, the other adds nothing for the same scenario

Comment: So the first one is better? @ClaudioRedi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a third option that IMO is better. It uses [**collection if**](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour?utm_campaign=Flutter%2BWeekly%2BNewsletter&utm_medium=rss&utm_source=Flutter_Weekly_Newsletter_1#collection-operators)

```
Widget buildItem(){
    return Column(children: <Widget>[
      if (this.widget.showItem1) Row(children: <Widget>[Container(), Container()]),
      if (this.widget.showItem2) Row(children: <Widget>[Container(), Container()]),
      if (this.widget.showItem3) Row(children: <Widget>[Container(), Container()])
    ]);
  }
```

It's a mix of the two approaches.